# reporteRs "table of content"

Tags: r, reporters

I am using a docx template in reporteRs, using bookmarks to replace text and add tables (empty_template = FALSE). I also have bookmarked the posistion of the table of content. This does not seem to work and the table of content is inserted at the end of the document. Is there a way I can insert the TOC in its proper place?

Answer (score 0):

`addTOC` does not support `bookmark` argument. Package officer has `body_add_toc` and `cursor_bookmark` that should do the job.